# Class TKApplication is implemented in two places

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, tkinter

Matplotlib is giving me a segfault. It seems like I installed tkinter in two places. Does anyone have an advice for this situation?

```
In [1]: from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
objc[10264]: Class TKApplication is implemented in both /usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib/libtk8.6.dylib and /System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Tk. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[10264]: Class TKMenu is implemented in both /usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib/libtk8.6.dylib and /System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Tk. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[10264]: Class TKContentView is implemented in both /usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib/libtk8.6.dylib and /System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Tk. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[10264]: Class TKWindow is implemented in both /usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib/libtk8.6.dylib and /System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Tk. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

In [2]: plt.plot([1,2,3], [6,5,4])
Out[2]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x11081d0d0>]

In [3]: plt.show()
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: How did you install tk?  I suggest using one of the two methods to un-install one of them.  There maybe some path-related magic you need as well.  Also try using the OSX or qt backends for mpl instead of tk.

Comment: Its been so long I forgot how I installed tkinter. Lately I've tried reinstalling it with `brew install python --with-brewed-tk` which has not been successful.

Comment: Notoriously hard to install on OSX? Get ActivePython from ActiveState. It's trivial to install.

Comment: @BryanOakley I downloaded this as part of my initial attempt to solve this problem. It did not help. Was it the wrong download? http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads

Comment: @kilojoules: yep, that's the right one. You found that version hard to install?

Comment: @BryanOakley I installed this package before posting my problem. Installing the package did not effect my issue - do I need to do anything else to link to that version of tKinter?

Comment: Something I feel I should mention: I'm using gcc built python

Comment: My comment wasn't that installing ActivePython will solve the problem. You stated Tkinter was "notoriously hard" to install, and I merely suggested that installing it isn't necessarily hard.

Comment: ok. I edited my question to remove that statement. I have had many problems installing tKinter and I find the process much less that straight-forward. IMO downloading and installing a package are different.

Comment: Getting the scientific stack to install and working correctly on mac _is_ notoriously difficult given the volume of questions on SO and issues we see reported upstream to mpl.  It is not cool to give less experienced folks grief like that.

Comment: Apple comes with an old version of tcl/tk.  When installing Python, one should install a newer version of tcl/tk (without removing the Apple-installed version).  This page, https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/, discussin this and had a section `How Python Chooses Which Tk Library To Use`.  That section might help you.